# SQL CASE WHEN <Value> IN Slow on SQL Server 2005 but not 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I have a very simple query that is driving me absolutely nuts.

Here's the situation:

- I have two database servers.
- One is an old SQL Server 2000 (VM), very minimal resources.
- The other is a very large SQL Server 2005 enterprise cluster with an absolutely ridiculous amount of resources available.
- I have a small portion of a larger query that executes in 3 seconds and returns 50,000+ rows of data on SQL Server 2000
- This same small query takes upwards of 15 minutes to return 1000 rows on SQL Server 2005
- The database I'm working with is a mirror image on these two servers. Same tables, same data in tables, same indexes on tables, etc.

I've tried creating different indexes on the SQL Server 2005 tables, defragged all the indexes that exist, updated table statistics, etc. Nothing has been able to make this query run faster on SQL Server 2005. Currently nothing else is running against the SQL Server 2005 server, and our DBAs assure me it's not a configuration issue or anything to do with feature deprecation between SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005.

The query is below:

```
SELECT (CASE 
             WHEN TeamMember.ID IN  (SELECT DISTINCT ProjMgrID FROM ProjMgr)
                THEN 'Yes' 
                ELSE 'No' 
        END) AS OnProjAsMgr 
FROM TeamMember
```

So return a distinct list of all the ProjMgrs, and if the TeamMember is on that list then assign "Yes" to the OnProjAsMgr value.

I'm a total SQL newbie, and this is code written by a predecessor.  I don't know if there's a better way to write it, but I cannot figure out why it runs great on SQL Server 2000 but completely implodes on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: And can you describe the indexes on the table, and whether statistics have been updated and compatibility level has been moved to 90 since the database was attached/restored on the 2005 server?

Comment: Any chance the data on the cluster might span multiple storage units on a SAN? We had some bizarro SQL performance problems many moons ago, and after some blood, sweat, and tears we found out that part of the problem was tied to a factor like this - not exactly the same, but your problem at least rang that bell. Just a thought.

Comment: The query plan for SQL2000 - http://i49.tinypic.com/2wrnuih.png
The query plan for SQL2005 - http://i50.tinypic.com/30n9cuw.png

I've been looking at these, but I'm not really sure how to read them and Google hasn't really been helpful.

I saw the table scan, and thought to try some indexes on the 2005 server, but that just replaced table scan with "index scan" and it still took just as long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DISTINCT causes a sort, and IN causes the entire query to be evaluated. How does this version work:

```
SELECT OnProjAsMgr = CASE WHEN EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ProjMgr WHERE ProjMgrID = TeamMember.ID)
  THEN 'Yes' 
  ELSE 'No' 
  END
FROM dbo.TeamMember;
```

If that fares no better then I suspect indexes are missing and no query will perform well without them.

Comment: Hi Aaron, Your first query works perfectly and executes in a second! Thank you!  I'm not sure how to interpret "SELECT 1"?  Could you explain a little more when you say IN causes the entire query to be re-evaluated?

The second query with the join returns ~600,000 rows instead of the ~50000 rows I want, I assume because the DISTINCT is needed?

Comment: To be clear, there are duplicate values of ProjMgrID in ProjMgr

Comment: Yes, apparently distinct is needed. SELECT 1 could be SELECT * or SELECT any column. The optimizer knows it does not have to return any data so it doesn't actually matter what you put in the select list. I put SELECT 1 because then it's clear to other readers that no data is returned. The statement that it is evaluated (not re-evaluated) meant that when you say IN, the whole query needs to be resolved. With EXISTS, as soon as a single row is found for that criteria, it exits, often saving many reads.

Comment: Ah, got it!  Thank you again, you have totally saved the day for me! :)

Out of curiosity, do you have any idea why this might cause such a slowdown on SQL Server 2005 but not on SQL Server 2000?  Could it be some kind of caching effect?

Comment: Like I asked in a comment above, (a) did you update stats? (b) have you set compat level to 90? These things (and others, such as session settings) can affect query plans. Unfortunately the differences are hard to tell from screen shots of plans; they're buried in the XML. Posting .sqlplan files will usually be better.

Comment: Hey Aaron, the stats on all the tables have been updated, and the compatibility level is 90 according to my DBAs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "better" way, but here's a *different* way that you can try:

```
SELECT ... other fields you want ...,
       CASE WHEN ProjMgr.ProjMgrID IS NULL
            THEN 'No'
            ELSE 'Yes'
        END AS OnProjAsMgr
  FROM TeamMember
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN ProjMgr
    ON ProjMgr.ProjMgrID = TeamMember.ID
;
```

Notes:

- On some DBMSes, this will perform much better than your query, but I don't know whether it would perform better on SQL Server 2005, given that your query already works fine on SQL Server 2000. I think you'll just have to try it.
- Your query uses `SELECT DISTINCT ProjMgrID FROM ProjMgr`. If that is actually different from `SELECT ProjMgrID FROM ProjMgr` — that is, if there are actually duplicate values of `ProjMgrID` in `ProjMgr` — then the above query is not exactly equivalent to yours, since it will give a separate record for each duplicate. You might have to add a `GROUP BY` clause in that case.
- For that matter, if `SELECT DISTINCT ProjMgrID FROM ProjMgr` is equivalent to `SELECT ProjMgrID FROM ProjMgr` for your data, as I suspect, then it also might be worth removing the `DISTINCT`, since that might affect the optimizer as well.

Comment: This could result in a different amount of rows, notice the distinct in the subquery. It indicate that there are several identical ProjMgrID in ProjMgr

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: I mentioned that in my notes.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT (
    CASE WHEN P.ID IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
) AS OnProjAsMgr
FROM TeamMember AS T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProjMgr AS P ON T.ID=P.ID
```

Comment: how is this different from @Ruakh's answer ?

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would make this even more understandable to current and future readers.